# How to use lodash or any other JavaScript package inside Dittofi?

Tags: javascript

How to use lodash (https://lodash.com/) or any other JavaScript package inside Dittofi?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the lodash CDN from [here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/lodash)

In the Dittofi front-end builder, go to the Home Page settings ("Edit Page Settings"). In there you will see an option to add "Custom code" (it's the last option).

Since lodash is JavaScript, you will need to add a `script` tag with the cdn as the `src` attribute in the "Before  tag" section and hit Save.

I.e., in the "Before  tag" section, put in `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>` and save.